# How to set the innerHTML of an element from another file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the value of HTML file using a javascript of another HTML file.

for example :

```
html1.html 
js1.js // this is for html1.html

html2.html // inside this html file, I wanted to set the value and innerHTML of 1 element using js1.js
```

for example element:

```
 <input id="cID" name="cID" type="text" class="required form-control">
```

IS there anyway to achieve it??

Thank you and Regards,

Comment: How will you take the html form one page to another using JS ? generally we pass only values from one page to another using querystring or session etc ! 
What are you trying to achieve !

Comment: @VinodkumarG , on the comment beside html2.html sir, I want to achieve on how to set the value of element inside html2.html using the javascript of html1.html

Comment: you can't do that. you can only load html2.html into thml1.html and change it there. but it won't be saved.

Comment: You can set value in localStorage or globally and then use it. But for that also you need a separate `js` file for `html2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's at least really impractical.

HTML pages "aren't made"(well, it's what I want any new dev to think anyway) to communicate with each others. Sure, you **can** make it happen by either using iframe/popup/localStorage/cookies. But it **usually** is a bad solution to any problem you're having, with another simpler/better/stronger solution waiting for you to find it.

In details :

- Iframe solution : call html2 inside html1 and use
  [iframe.contentWindow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp)
- Popup solution : generate html2 from html1
  with [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)
- localStorage and cookie : necessitate a js in
  html2.html, then just stock the value in html1 and get it back in
  html2 ([cookie doc](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), [localStorage doc](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp))

Usually better solutions to problems generating this kind of question :

1. include js1.js in html2, nothing prevent you from including one JS
   multiple time (best solution, IF it's sufficient to solve the issue)
2. use a server-side solution like template, session, include,
   ajax... (nearly always the best solution if posssible)
3. just use one html, and change its content in JS (nearly always the
   best solution if solution 2 isn't possible)

Comment: Thank you sir.. I'll try to make it work with localstorage.